# Check browser width and fire event only once

Tags: javascript, function, browser, resize, window-resize

- I want to check my browser/window width, for when it is below 669px.
- When it is below 669px, I want to fire a function **only once**.
- However, every time I resize my browser than further less than 669px, why function keeps on firing, with every resize.

How do I only fire an event once, once the user hits below 669px?

Here's the code I'm working with:

```
const checkWindowWdith = () => {
    console.log(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 669) {
        //DO SOMETHING HERE
    };
};


//HERE I AM WAIT FOR THE USER TO FINISH RESIZING
var doit;
window.onresize = function(){
    clearTimeout(doit);
    doit = setTimeout(checkWindowWdith, 100);
};
```

Comment: Depending on your code you could just add `window.onresize = null` to `//DO SOMETHING HERE`. Might need to clear the timeout again as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to create a var who is set to false if the event was start and set to true if he never been start like this:

```js
var firstStartEvent = true

const checkWindowWdith = () => {
    console.log(document.documentElement.clientWidth);
    if (document.documentElement.clientWidth < 669) {
        firstStartEvent = false;
        //DO SOMETHING HERE
    };
};


//HERE I AM WAIT FOR THE USER TO FINISH RESIZING
var doit;
window.onresize = function(){
    clearTimeout(doit);
    if (firstStartEvent) {
      doit = setTimeout(checkWindowWdith, 100);
    }
};
```

Comment: Wow, this worked perfectly. Thank you so much Lucas!  Nice simply and clean idea.  I'll use this again going forwards in the future :)